# Estoy haciendo una lista simplemente enlazada, y al momento de borrar un elemento especifico me marca un error

Tags: java, lista, estructuras-de-datos

como dice el título estoy realizando una lista simplemente enlazada. Creo que el problema esta en el bucle pero no logro encontrarlo.

El error que marca es que `no puede leer el valor "valor" porque Current.next=null`, creo que se refiere que sigue recorriendo la lista aunque ya haya encontrado el nodo a eliminar.
Agradecería mucho que me pudieran ayudar.

```
public void BorrarValor(int valor) {
    if(head==null) {
      System.out.println("No hay nada");
            }
            else {
                
                if(head.valor==valor) {
                    head=head.next;
                }
                Nodo Current=head;

                do{
                
                    if(Current.next.valor==valor) {
                        Current=Current.next.next;                          
                    }else {
                        Current=Current.next;
                        
                    }
                    
                }while(Current!=null) ;//Fin while*/

    }//Fin del else             
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necesitas repasar la lógica de tu programa. Así no obtendrás ningún error ya que no intentarás acceder al valor de `null`.

Suponiendo que quieras borrar la primer aparición de un valor, debería ser algo así:

1. Si la variable `head` es `null` terminaste. Sino sigue al siguiente paso.
2. Si el nodo de la variable `head` tiene el valor, `head` pasa a ser el siguiente nodo y terminas. Sino sigue al siguiente paso.
3. Comienza con el primer nodo como nodo actual.
4. Si el siguiente nodo es `null` terminaste.
5. Si el valor del siguiente nodo es el esperado, elimina el nodo actual y terminaste.
6. Pasa al siguiente nodo.
7. Ve al paso 4.

Te quedaría un código así:

```
// Paso 1
if (head == null)
    return;

// Paso 2
if (head.valor == valor) {
    head = head.next;
    return;
}

// Paso 3, 4, 6 y 7
for (Nodo actual = head; actual.next != null; actual = actual.next){
    // Paso 5
    if (actual.next.valor == valor){
        current.next = current.next.next;
        return;
    }
}
```